# how to read data from a collection in laravel

Tags: laravel

Hi im new to laravel and i have this collection

```
$details = collect([
            ['total' => Valeur::all()->count()],
            ['instance' => Valeur::where('etat', 1)->count()],
            ['deposer' => Valeur::where('etat', 2)->count()],
            ['encaisse' => Valeur::where('etat', 3)->count()],
            ['retourne' => Valeur::where('etat', 4)->count()],
            ]);
```

i was wondering how to read data like this

```
$details->total;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have array of arrays then you will need to iterate over it in order to access it as you want. But to me it looks like this should be one item of an array, so if you change it like this:

```
$details = collect([
    'total' => Valeur::all()->count(),
    'instance' => Valeur::where('etat', 1)->count(),
    'deposer' => Valeur::where('etat', 2)->count(),
    'encaisse' => Valeur::where('etat', 3)->count(),
    'retourne' => Valeur::where('etat', 4)->count(),
]);
```

Then you will be able to access it like `$details->get('total');` or `$details['total']`.

Comment: @HamzaGhaissi I added an extra accessor option. You can use whatever you prefer.